# Microstrategy - Using a Pie as a selector

Tags: dashboard, microstrategy

I'm using the dashboards (not documents, falsh dashboards) in MSTR.
I'd like tu use an element of my chart as a selector to drill down.

For example if i have 4 pies representing departments I'd like to click on one of them to show the sales of the "sub-departments".

In the following link they show how to do it with documents:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZ_urHhJo7A

I'd like to do that with dashboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your Pie as selector for another Visualization (grid or graph) in your dashboard where you show lower level data (in your case the sub-departments).

Or if you want to continue to analyze the sub-departments in a pie chart, once you select a department you can click on the menu arrow on the top-right corner (sometimes it's a bit nasty to get it) and select Keep Only and Show -> Sub-departments.

Unfortunately I don't think you can do it with just a double click

[image]